# Sklearn GridSearchCV list of available kernels

Tags: scikit-learn

Where can I find a list of the strings that represent all available kernels for GridSearchCV from sklearn?

I have looked into the main doc page https://scikit-earn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html and wasn't able to find it.

For example: 'poly' (stands for Polynomial kernel), 'rbf', 'linear'...
What are that other strings for the other kernels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GridSearchCV has nothing to to with kernels.

`kernel` is a parameter of your estimator (e.g. sklearn.svm.SVC can use a kernel).
GridSearchCV just gives you the option to try different combinations of parameters for your estimator.

Long story short: you have to look at the estimator you use, eg. for sklearn.svm.SVC:

```
kernel : {'linear', 'poly', 'rbf', 'sigmoid', 'precomputed'}, default='rbf'
    Specifies the kernel type to be used in the algorithm.
    It must be one of 'linear', 'poly', 'rbf', 'sigmoid', 'precomputed' or
    a callable.
    If none is given, 'rbf' will be used. If a callable is given it is
    used to pre-compute the kernel matrix from data matrices; that matrix
    should be an array of shape ``(n_samples, n_samples)``.
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the list of kernels

```
['linear', 'poly', 'rbf', 'sigmoid']
```

you can check more detail in [this link](https://www.vebuso.com/2020/03/svm-hyperparameter-tuning-using-gridsearchcv/)